# How to workaround impossible inheritance from sealed class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, sealed

Today im working in WPF.

I tried to inherit from `System.Windows.Shapes.Line` class, like this:

```
class MyLine : System.Windows.Shapes.Line
{
    public Ln()
    {
        this.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    }
}
```

I just realized, that Line class is sealed.

My goal is to create a class, that will work like `Line` class (to put it on `Canvas`), but I don't want to mess my code with adding brush to it everytime, lets say always want black brush/stroke with 2px width.

I feel im trying to do it wrong.

How should I do that?

Comment: use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @retailcoder Can you write some example?

Comment: Why not instantiate a line instance and set the color? If you want it common wrap it in a static factory helper or something

Comment: @devshorts I like the factory helper work-around - create a class, like, `LineFactory` that exposes a method which returns a `Line` that's configured as specified by the factory method's parameters.

Comment: @retailcoder now finally I understood what class factory is... And composition is just putting Line class inside my MyLine class? I think I got it. Btw. Shall I delete question, or someone will write answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a factory class:

```
public class LineFactory
{
    public Line Create(<parameters here>)
    {
        //create and return a Line object
    }
}
```

The factory could also be `static`, but that could hinder testability.

Note that this solution doesn't let you *extend* the `Line` class as inheritance would. To do that you would need to return a `MyLine` class which would embed a `Line` object along with the additional properties you'd want `MyLine` to have.

```
public class MyLine
{
    private Line _theBoringOriginal; // composition: "has-a" (vs inheritance "is-a")
    public MyLine(Line line)
    {
        _theBoringOriginal = line;
    }

    public foo SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If it's just methods you want to extend the `Line` class with, you don't need a new class, you could just write extension methods in a static class:

```
public static foo DoSomethingCool(this Line line, <parameters here>)
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Static classes are ok (from a testing standpoint) as long as they themselves are under test and do not rely on external dependencies.

Comment: @JustinPihony I see, you can't constructor-inject dependencies in a static (no instance) class! Thing is, it's likely that the factory class will be some other SUT's dependency and *that* would/could be problematic, no? I'm a little green on testing and read everywhere that `static` is a big no-no for that, so I just steer away from anything static.

Comment: It would not be problematic as long as it is a deterministic method with no side effects and the method is under test. Something like `Math.Round` As a note, the static File methods are bad since they are dependent on the file system

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply create an extension class to do what you want?  Extension classes were create specifically to allow you to extend sealed classes with new methods, without having to actually inherit things.

```
public static class LineExtensions {
    // returns the Line so you can use it fluently
    public static Line MakeLineBlack(this Line line) {
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        return line;
    }
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
var line = new Line().MakeLineBlack();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that you end up with chained calls that end up being nothing more than micro-configuring your line through static method calls which *could* end up looking like this: `line.MakeLineBlack().MakeLineDoubleDashDot().MakeLineHeavyWeight().MakeLineBlue().OopsThoughtItWasBlack().MakeLineDoubleDashDot().OopsAlreadySaidThat()....` - vs a factory method that simply creates what is says it creates (e.g. `CreateBlackDoubleDashDotHeavyWeightLine()`) and does it in a single call. Not sure *when* or *why* going down the static road could be an *absolute* necessity.

Comment: @retailcoder - It's more a preference than anything else.  Using fluent methods, I can mix-and-match without writing additional code, with your approach you have to write a new method if you want CreateBlackHeavyWeightLine(), I simply have to call Line.Black().HeavyWeight()

Comment: I'd prefer `PaintIt (Black)` over `Black ()` because otherwise the fluent syntax doesn't add much to just directly setting the property, and having a static class with methods to set every possible value of every settable property, smells like YAGNI to me (if you're not going to need a new ext.method it means you already wrote it).